# not getting the result i want in MYSQL using group by and case

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by

i have 2 tables and i want to get result by using group by and case like this

| title | ViewersCount | EditorsCount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Recog | 6 | 6 |
| Mile | 4 | 2 |

instead of i am getting this result

| title | ViewersCount | EditorsCount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Recog | null | 6 |
| Recog | 6 | null |
| Mile | null | 2 |
| Mile | 4 | null |

My Query is like below

```sql
select distinct
  (db.title),
  case when da.type ="VIEW" then count(da.user_id) END as  ViewersCount,
  case when da.type ="EDIT" then count(da.user_id) End as EditorsCount
from dashboard db 
left join dashboard_access da 
  on db.id = da.dashboard_id
group by db.title,da.type;
```

Comment: what if you do "group by db.title";

Comment: then it gives error of da.type that needs to be in GROUP BY

Comment: can you create sql fiddle with sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by title only in order to get one result row per title. Put the conditions inside `COUNT` then. This is called conditional aggregation and gets the result you are after.

```
select 
  db.title,
  count(case when da.type = 'VIEW' then 1 end) as viewerscount,
  count(case when da.type = 'EDIT' then 1 end) as editorscount
from dashboard db 
left join dashboard_access da on db.id = da.dashboard_id
group by db.title
order by db_title;
```